SAP Hybris promotion custom action bean error
I created the following class in SAP Hybris.
package tr.nttdata.csa.csapromotionengineservices.rule.ruledifinitons.conditions;

public class Task9ProductNameAction extends AbstractRuleExecutableSupport {

    private final String SELECT_OPERATOR = "selectOperator";

    @Override
    public void performAction(RuleActionContext context) {
        performActionInternal(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean performActionInternal(RuleActionContext context) {
        CartRAO cart = context.getValue(CartRAO.class);
        Set<OrderEntryRAO> orderEntries = cart.getEntries();
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(orderEntries)) return false;

        Task9Operator discountType = (Task9Operator) context.getParameter(SELECT_OPERATOR);
        BigDecimal discountAmount = (BigDecimal) context.getParameter("discountAmount");

        Optional<OrderEntryRAO> targetEntryOptional = getTargetEntry(orderEntries, discountType);

        if (targetEntryOptional.isPresent()){
            OrderEntryRAO orderEntry = targetEntryOptional.get();
            applyDiscount(context, orderEntry, discountAmount);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private Optional<OrderEntryRAO> getTargetEntry(Set<OrderEntryRAO> orderEntries, Task9Operator discountType){
        if (discountType == Task9Operator.LOWEST){
            return orderEntries.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(OrderEntryRAO::getTotalPrice));
        } else if (discountType == Task9Operator.HIGHEST){
            return orderEntries.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(OrderEntryRAO::getTotalPrice));
        } else {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

    private void applyDiscount(RuleActionContext context, OrderEntryRAO orderEntry, BigDecimal discountAmount){
        DiscountRAO discount = new DiscountRAO();
        discount.setValue(discountAmount);
        discount.setAppliedToQuantity(orderEntry.getQuantity());

        RuleEngineResultRAO result = context.getRuleEngineResultRao();
        result.getActions().add(discount);

        setRAOMetaData(context, discount);
        context.insertFacts(discount);
        context.scheduleForUpdate(orderEntry, orderEntry.getOrder(), result);
    }
}

Then I defined the bean in promotionengineservices-spring.xml file as follows.
<alias name="task9ProductNameAction" alias="task9ProductNameAction"/>
    <bean id="task9ProductNameAction" parent="abstractRuleExecutableSupport"
          class="tr.nttdata.csa.csapromotionengineservices.rule.evaluation.actions.Task9ProductNameAction">
    </bean>

And finally I wrote the following impexes.
INSERT_UPDATE RuleActionDefinition; id[unique = true]                    ; priority; translatorId                   ; translatorParameters                        ; categories(id)
; y_product_name_action         ; 350     ; ruleExecutableActionTranslator ; actionId->task9ProductNameAction            ; product_discounts

INSERT_UPDATE RuleActionDefinitionParameter; definition(id)[unique = true] ; id[unique = true] ; priority  ; type                                                                              ; value; required[default = true]
                                      ; y_product_name_action         ; selectOperator    ; 150       ; Enum(tr.nttdata.csa.csapromotionengineservices.rule.ruledifinitons.Task9Operator) ;      ;
                                           ; y_product_name_action         ; discountAmount    ; 150       ; java.math.BigDecimal                                                              ;      ;

INSERT_UPDATE RuleActionDefinitionRuleTypeMapping; definition(id)[unique = true]          ; ruleType(code)[default = 'PromotionSourceRule'][unique = true]
; y_product_name_action         ;

As I expected, all the fields come in the correct format with localization processing, but when I want to publish the promotion, I get the following error.
INFO  [00055LBU::de.hybris.platform.ruleengineservices.jalo.RuleEngineJob] (00055LBU) [AbstractRuleEngineJob] *************************************
INFO  [00055LBU::de.hybris.platform.ruleengineservices.jalo.RuleEngineJob] (00055LBU) [AbstractRuleEngineJob] Starting RuleEngineCompilePublishJob
INFO  [00055LBU::de.hybris.platform.ruleengineservices.jalo.RuleEngineJob] (00055LBU) [AbstractRuleEngineJob] *************************************
ERROR [00055LBU::de.hybris.platform.ruleengineservices.jalo.RuleEngineJob] (00055LBU) [DefaultRuleMaintenanceService] The rule compilation finished with errors
ERROR [00055LBU::de.hybris.platform.ruleengineservices.jalo.RuleEngineJob] (00055LBU) [AbstractRuleEngineJob] Rule Code "task9_promotion": "No bean found for action"
INFO  [00055LBU::de.hybris.platform.ruleengineservices.jalo.RuleEngineJob] (00055LBU) [AbstractRuleEngineJob] *************************************
INFO  [00055LBU::de.hybris.platform.ruleengineservices.jalo.RuleEngineJob] (00055LBU) [AbstractRuleEngineJob] RuleEngineCompilePublishJob finished with errors
INFO  [00055LBU::de.hybris.platform.ruleengineservices.jalo.RuleEngineJob] (00055LBU) [AbstractRuleEngineJob] *************************************



Package Path seems incorrect should be following in bean definition.
tr.nttdata.csa.csapromotionengineservices.rule.ruledifinitons.conditions.Task9ProductNameAction 
